# Drupal 6: set pager_query() to display last page of query?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, pagination

Does anyone here know how to set up a pager_query() to automatically go to the last page of the query when the page is displayed?  I'm using theme_pager() to format the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

drupal_goto: http://site.com/views_page_link?page=LastPageNum
determine LastPageNum via quering count of result divided counts of elements to show.

Comment: Thanks.  Not exactly what I was looking for, but it did actually answer my question as asked.  I was just hoping to be able to do this without specifying a URL like that, as I'm using this in a module where the URL is coming through the hook_menu, which alters the ? and = characters.

Comment: it's very simple: in menu create this:  http://site.com/views_page_link/last. Then in menu header add php code, that will see "last"==arg(1) and drupal_goto to last num as i show.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand.  I'll work on this when I get a chance and reply when I get it to work.  Thanks!